# How would I make the color of squares change when they are clicked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, onclicklistener

I have written it out using an event listener but it does not work and the squares remain black even when they are clicked. I found a few typos that I fixed but I am not sure whether I was correct in using `getElementsByClassName`.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    .square {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: 5px;
     }
   </style>
  </head>
 <body>

 <div id="container">
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 </div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Javascript:

```
var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('square');

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
squares[0].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor(event) {
event.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}


function randomColor() {

var randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
//create the string that is the ‘random color’
var randomColor = "rgb("+randomRed+","+randomGreen+","+randomBlue+")";

return randomColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic problems:

1. Your for loop has a hardcoded `squares[0]` when it should be `squares[i]`, so you're binding the handler to the first element multiple times and not to the others.
2. The `event` object doesn't have a `style` property. Use `this.style.backgroundColor` - within the handler `this` will refer to the clicked element. Or use `event.target.style.backgroundColor`.

So like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor(event) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oueLs5dp/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple. My codepen of the below changes working as intended. : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwgEdm

First, you need to modify your for loop, you are referencing index 0 instead of i:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
    }
```

Second, you need to reference 'this' within your change color function, and pass in e for the event object:

```
function changeColor(e) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't reloaded the page and seen nnnnnn's answer when I was writing this up and setting up the codepen. He answered it slightly before I did, please mark him as correct.

Answer (score -1):

Using `.addEventListener()` you would need to change:

```
function changeColor(event) {
event.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}
```

to

```
function changeColor(){
  // not using Event Object
  this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}
```

, but let's face it `.getElementsByClassName()` is not backward compatible anyways.

I recommend the following:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function inArray(x, a){
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === x){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function getElementsByClass(className, element){
  var r = false;
  var el = element ? element : doc;
  if(el.getElementsByClassName){
    r = el.getElementsByClassName(className);
  }
  else{
    var all = el.getElementsByTagName('*'), l = all.length;
    if(l > 0){
      r = [];
      for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
        var s = all[i].className.split(/\s/);
        if(inArray(className, s))r.push(all[i]);
      }
  }
  return r;
}
function randomColor(context){
  context.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+Math.floor(Math.rand()*256)+','+Math.floor(Math.rand()*256)+','+Math.floor(Math.rand()*256)+')';
}
```

Now it's like:

```
var all = getElementsByClass('square');
for(var i=0,l=all.length; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){ // in case you want to add more array stuff
    all[i].onclick = function(){
      randomColor(this);
      // do more stuff here
    }
  })(i); // end of closure
}
```

Note: `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and .9 repeating, never 1. You'll never get 255 with your current formula.

Comment: Does your custom `getElementsByClass()` function work if an element has more than one class assigned?

Answer (score -1):

You should use JQuery to do this, it is relatively easy. put this link between your head tags: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` And then put this code in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.square').click(function(){
        $('.square').addClass('green');
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/yd6qpL3u/)

Comment: *"You should use jQuery"* - No, you have the option of using jQuery. There's no "should" here. It's easy enough without jQuery.

Comment: @nnnnnn That is a matter of opinion

Comment: I like jQuery. I use it. I recommend it. But I still say "should" is overstating it, especially when the OP didn't tag the question with it. And especially when the code in the question only needed six characters changed to work perfectly. This is not a difficult thing to implement in vanilla JS.

Comment: This is a pure javascript question Joshua. Saying "use framework/library xyz" doesn't help people who are trying to learn and understand raw JS/HTML.